# Last few tasks of Spark job are taking long time to complete?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I was doing UNION ALL two table in Data bricks Spark Scala. But when I was writing the resultant dataframe into a delta table it is so much of time to complete. Below is the code spinet I was do.

```
val df1=spark.sql(
s"""
select
nb.*,
facl.id as facl_decn_id,
facl.seq_nbr as facl_decn_seq_nbr,
case when facl.id is not null then concat(substr(nb.open_dttm, 1, 10), ' 00:00:00.000') else cast(null as string) end as eng_dt
from Interim.Interim_nobed nb
left outer join Interim.facl_decn_interim facl_bed on
(nb.id=facl.id and nb.facl_decn_id=facl.id)
where nb.facl_decn_id is not null""")
```

```
val df2=spark.sql(
s"""
select
nb.*,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_id,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_seq_nbr,
cast(null as string) as eng_dt
from Interim.Interim_nobed nb
where nb.facl_decn_id is null
""")
```

```
val df3=df1.coalesce(150)
val df4=df2.coalesce(150)
```

```
val df5=df3.unionAll(df4)
```

Here df5 is holding the final UNION ALL results. Then I tried to write the data frame into delta table.  It is taking so much of time at few of tasks at last of a stage.

```
df5.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(s"Interim.set1_interim")
```

**UPDATE:**
Here **Interim.Interim_nobed** table is having 30 columns and the key columns are id and facl_decn_id. When I checked the count of this two column using group by I found
for column facl_decn_id there were 90% NULL values compared with total count.

And table **Interim.facl_decn_interim** has only two columns id and
bed_day_decn_seq_nbr did group by on both column found seq_nbr having more count for few than other.

Comment: how sure are you about the `.coalesce(150)`? it will reshuffle the data and take a long time depending on the size.

Comment: The tables are very large so tried with 150.

Comment: have you tried the code without the `.coalesce()`?

Comment: Yes, even same issue. Also tried with Repartition.

Comment: 1. ... facl.id ... what is facl ?. In part FROM we see left outer join Interim.facl_decn_interim facl_bed on ...
2. please show columns in Interim.Interim_nobed nb  ,,, nb.*
3. ... where nb.facl_decn_id is not null  and if see ... facl.id as facl_decn_id, ... You have two column in dataframe with name "facl_decn_id". it is not good.

Comment: please, 
1. val df1 = spark.table("Interim.Interim_nobed")
2. val df2 = spark.table("Interim.facl_decn_interim")
and please, show result
df1.printSchema() and df2.printSchema()

Comment: Hi mvasyliv. I have updated question pls check.